# How to set a default Account within a contact record for a user profile?

Tags: account, contact, default-value

I am wondering if there is a way to set the default Account ID within a Contact record for a specific user profile?

I have tried workflow rules (doesn't allow field updates against lookup), I considered record types then remembered that default values sit against fields not page layouts etc.  I couldn't use process builder as I can't confirm the user is from a specific profile. I am hoping to avoid apex/visualforce...

Thanks.